# Preparing for a Scientific Programmer/HPC programmer Interview

Tags: hpc, scientific-computing

Could you recommend sources/literature to prepare for Scientific Programmer/HPC programmer Interview?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Introduction to High-Performance Scientific Computing" by Victor Eijkhout is a very good book to start with (and is relatively up to date). You can find it freely on [his personal home page](https://pages.tacc.utexas.edu/~eijkhout/istc/istc.html).

As this book mainly focus especially on quite theoretical/abstract concepts, you probably need to complete the book with *practical HPC programming*. *MPI* and *OpenMP* are two programming standard massively used in HPC applications. As a result, I strongly advise you to learn how to program with both, especially from *practical exercises*.
There is a *lot* of resource you can find on internet for both. If you don't now how to start, please look [here](https://mpitutorial.com/) for MPI and [here](https://www.openmp.org/resources/tutorials-articles/) for OpenMP.